# Probit analysis using 13 cases and checking normal distribution

Tags: regression, binary-data, probit

Can I use probit if my dependent variable has data that looks something like this, 1 case is equal to 0, and 12 cases are equal to 1?
Thanks

Comment: How does checking the normal distribution enter your question?  What are the covariates involved with this data? It doesn't look like you have good information to fit a curve regardless of the method.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I think he is mainly asking if he has 13 observations and only one of the binary dependent outcome is 0 and the other 12 are equal to 1, then will probit model work well? It seems like he has a clear assumption that the underlying variable is normal, in other words, P[Y=1|X] takes the form of a normal cumulative distribution. He is getting tensed with if probit works well with only one 0 in the outcome variable.

Comment: Sure the probit won't work well and neither would the logistic.  That is what I was saying and what you mean is that P[X|Y=1] is approximately normal.  He did mention checking normality in the title of the question though.

Comment: @Michael, for the record this question is incredibly vague (OP, help!) but I don't see what relevance $P(X|Y=1)$ (and whether or not that conditional distribution is normal) could possibly have. Blain's interpretation of the question - does $P(Y=1|X) = \Phi( X \beta)$ (vs. some other link function, e.g. $1/(1+e^{-X \beta}))$? - does seem more plausible. I think the answer is that there's no way you're going to be able use a data set with $n=13$ to see whether the probit or the logistic (or some other link function) is more appropriate.

Comment: @Macro My point is P(Y=1|X) can't be a normal distribution, it is a single value. That it could equal a cumulative normal probability as you interpret is a different matter.

Comment: OK, @Michael. As I'd imagine you know, data arising from a probit regression can be thought of as thresholding (at 0) a variable with a normal distribution with mean $X \beta$ and variance $1$, similarly to how a logistic regression model arises from thresholding a logistic random variable. I assumed familiarity with this formulation is what lead to the OP's question but I could be wrong. Clearly we need more clarification to help him/her but I doubt a whole lot can be done with $n=13$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any statistical algorithm on any data it will successfully compute with.

The underlying questions are (1) would this be meaningful? and (2) would it have any power to detect anything?  The answers in this case are yes and no, respectively.

The analysis begins by looking at a dataset like the one described. Let's take the x-values to be evenly spaced. Because there's essentially no difference between the applicability of probit and logistic models, I will perform this analysis with the logit in `R`:

```
x <- 1:13
y <- x==2
fit <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(fit)
```

The output shows nothing is significant:

```
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    0.712      2.297    0.31     0.76
x             -0.842      0.858   -0.98     0.33
```

I set the *second* $y$ value (corresponding to $x=2$) equal to $1$ because if the first (most extreme) value were $1$, the data would not enable us to determine how quickly the curve slopes down from the first to the second data point.  (The output will tell us the algorithm failed to converge.)

Here's what the fits and the p-values look like depending on where in the dataset the $1$ is located:

[image: Plots]

*(Fits are shown as the red curves.)*

None of the p-values gets any lower than 0.33: there's just no chance of getting a significant result.

This picture would not change much if we were to change the distribution of the $x$ values to give the $1$ as much leverage as possible.  This is the best I can do with some experimentation:

[image: Best plot]

A p-value of $0.17$ would not be considered significant in most applications.  This answers the second question: **such a dataset just doesn't have the power to identify a relation between the response and the independent variable(s)**.

As to the first question, arguably the regression *can* be meaningful as an exploratory tool. But the graphics displayed here suggest the result is not any more informative than merely plotting the points.

Finally, what about alternative analyses? One possible application is to determine whether there is some relationship between $x$ and $y$. If the data are a random sample of a population, for instance, and we wanted to test the hypothesis that a $y$ value of $1$ is associated with *low* values of $x$ (a one-sided hypothesis), then we might apply a [Wilcoxon rank sum test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U).  Now, unlike with logistic or probit regression, there is no problem if the $1$ occurs at an extreme value of $x$:

```
x <- 1:13
y <- x==1
wilcox.test(x ~ y, alternative="greater")
```

The p-value of $0.07692 = 1/13$ is of course expressing the chance that the $1$ landed on the extreme value of $x$ at random.  But this is starting to get into the range of "suggestively significant" results.  We conclude that *if* the hypothesis is one-sided and *if* the solitary value of $y=1$ occurs for the expected *extreme* value of $x$, then there is some mild evidence of the association.

Comment: what is the red line in each of your plots? Is that the fitted probability?

Comment: @Macro It sure is.  I'll edit the post to stipulate that.