# What's the recommended way to visualise the result of a binary logistic regression with a continuous predictor variable, in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, binary-data

The other variables are categorical and I've used bar plots for them, but would like your opinions on how to visualise the results for a continuous variable, from a binary regression

Comment: If you wanted to do the reverse, plot the continuous values present in two groups, how would you do it?

Comment: Examples: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69873/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/525877/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/314363/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14501/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35370/919.

Comment: Note the within-the-bar bias, [Newman & Scholl (2012)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2Fs13423-012-0247-5), and consider dot plots for your categorical variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just plot the predictions on the same axis as the data?

[image]

If your model has several predictors, you are going to have to either fix them or predict across a grid and color the lines accordingly, like so

[image]